# How to Serialize/deserialize object with XStream, which has xml property in it?

Tags: xml, serialization, xstream

I am using XStream to serialize/deserialize Java Object. It is simple pojo class, but on of it's properties is also xml. How do i serialization works fine, but i am unable to deserialize it.

Example:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {

   .....
   String xmlProperty;
   ....
}
```

Because this xmlProperty is also xml XStream have trouble deserializing it. 
The error i receive is:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 32; columnNumber: 25; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
```

Comment: Could you post what the xmlProperty looks like, and how you serialize it?